# how to use solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilter standalone

Tags: java, lucene, solr, tokenize

At this point I'm pretty sure I've searched enough and I can't find a nice example of how put to work this class.

I've been looking for a good set of tokenizers and of course the solr/lucene *collection* is what I found (so far)

Now I'm looking for a good example of the use of this tokenizer, is there any good site/doc where I can find something like this?

ps. Maybe another set/library of tokeninzers might help

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to use the class as a standalone class ?

If so, the testcases would the best place to look for the usage e.g. 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_3/solr/src/test/org/apache/solr/analysis/TestWordDelimiterFilter.java

Lucene comes with a variation of [Tokenizers and filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters).
And you and pretty much use the classes stand alone.

Let me know if i am totally off what you need.